# How do I unit test a custom context manager?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, contextmanager

I have the following function that yields a `pyodbc.connect()` object to use with a `with` statement:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import pyodbc

@contextmanager
def get_db_connection(conn_string, **kwargs):
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, **kwargs)
        yield conn
    except Exception as connection_error:
        raise ValueError('Could not connect to db.', connection_error) from None
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

I'd like to write unit tests for this function to test that a connection can be opened, closed, and when an error occurs, a `ValueError` is raised. I have:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from db.query import get_db_connection

@patch('db.query.pyodbc.connect')
def test_get_db_connection(self, mock_connect):
    conn_string = Mock()
    with get_db_connection(conn_string) as conn:
        pass
    # print(conn) is acceptable here and prints:
    # <MagicMock name='connect()' id='2595126451264'>
    mock_connect.assert_called_once()

    mock_connect.side_effect = Exception()
    def _t():
        with get_db_connection(conn_string) as conn:
            pass

    self.assertRaises(UnboundLocalError, _t)
```

Everything here runs and passes, but I've noticed the `conn` is available after the `with` statement scope should be closed.

How do I write a unit test for `get_db_connection()` using `mock` so that the `conn` variables behave as I'd expect them? Or is there another way to sufficiently unit test it?

Comment: It *is* behaving as suggested. The name assigned to by a `with` statement does not go out of scope after the `with` statement completes. (Also, there is no such thing as a "`with` statement scope"; like any other compound statement aside from `def`, `with` does not create a new scope for its body.)

Comment: In this case, calling `_t` does produce that because there is no yielded `conn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

- `conn.close.assert_not_called()` to check that the connection is opened in the first `with` block.
- `conn.close.assert_called_once()` to check that the connection is closed after the first `with` block.
- There is already a check for no connection being established when an error occurs in the `try` block - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'conn' referenced before assignment